# How to limit Deno memory and cpu usage

Tags: deno

How can I limit Deno RAM and CPU usage when running js/ts scripts?

```
deno run https://deno.land/std@0.87.0/examples/welcome.ts
```

Comment: Is running it in a docker container an alternative you could consider? Since limiting memory and cpu usage is one of the benefits with containers.

Comment: @Jonas Yes, this is an alternative. Yesterday I found that you can limit memory usage by using v8 flags, for example: `deno run --v8-flags=--max-old-space-size=4 --allow-read fill-mem.js`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides using the container as sugessted in comments:

```
  --max-old-space-size (max size of the old space (in Mbytes))
        type: size_t  default: --max-old-space-size=0
  --max-heap-size (max size of the heap (in Mbytes) both max_semi_space_size and max_old_space_size take precedence. All three flags cannot be specified at the same time.)
        type: size_t  default: --max-heap-size=0
```

As suggested by [Luke Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4970632/luke-davis) in comments:

```
deno run --v8-flags='--max-heap-size=50,--max-old-space-size=50' \
    https://deno.land/std@0.87.0/examples/welcome.ts
// OR
export V8_FLAGS="--max-heap-size=50,--max-old-space-size=50";
deno run --v8-flags="${V8_FLAGS}" ./deno_example.ts
```

Comment: I get `Found argument '--max-heap-size' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context` in deno 1.17.0. Seems these config options are no longer available?

Comment: Seems the following syntax is required for newer deno versions: `deno run --v8-flags=--max-heap-size=50,--max-old-space-size=50'`.